# Parent component does not rerender after updating its state through child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I checked some of the threads about this and tried to fix it, but no succes yet.

I have a parent and a child component. In the parent component, I declare a state and pass the function to update this state on to my child component.

```
  function ProfileGallery() {
  const [selectedPet, setPet] = useState(null);
  const [filterText, setFilterText] = useState('');
  const [pets, setPets] = useState([]);
  const [componentState, setState] = useState('test');

  const updateState = (state) => {
        setState(...state);
      };

  return (
       <PetInformation
                selectedPet={selectedPet}
                componentState={componentState}
                triggerParentUpdate={updateState}
              />
);
}
```

In my child component, I do the following:

```
function PetInformation({ componentState, triggerParentUpdate, ...props }) {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('Delete succesful');
  const { selectedPet } = { ...props } || {};
  const updatedComponentState = 'newState';

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === 'Delete pending') {
      deletePet(selectedPet).then(() => setStatus('Delete succesful'));
    }
  }, [status]);

  const handleDelete = () => {
    setStatus('Delete pending');
  };

return (
    <button
            className="btn btn-primary pull-right"
            onClick={() => {
              handleDelete();
              triggerParentUpdate(updatedComponentState);
            }}
            type="button"
          >
            Delete Pet
    </button>
```

There's of course more code in between, but this shows the gist of what I'm trying to achieve. I want to delete an item I selected in my gallery and have that delete reflected once I click the delete button -> my ProfileGallery needs to re-render. I'm trying to do this by passing that function to update my state on to the child component. I know JS won't consider state changed if the reference remains the same, so that's why I am passing a new const updatedComponentState on, since that should have a different reference from my original componentState.

Everything works, the item gets removed but I still need to manually refresh my app before it gets reflected in the list in my gallery. Why won't ReactJS re-render my ProfileGallery component here? Isn't my state getting updated?

Comment: The code as written looks like it should force the parent to update **once**. In `updateState` you probably meant `setState(state)`, not `setState(...state)`. The latter spreads out the string as discrete arguments, and the state setter will ignore all but the first, so you end up setting your state to `"n"` the first time. (The second time onward you're passing the same string, so it won't update anything).

Comment: This kind of forced synthetic update is **poor practice**. Instead, keep the actual state information you need at each level in the hierarchy, and update it accordingly. It's fine for a child to call back to the parent to do an update, but it should be real state information that's being updated.

Comment: FYI, `const { selectedPet } = { ...props } || {};` should just be `const { selectedPet } = props;`, for two reasons: 1. There's no reason to make a copy of `props` and then throw it away. 2. Even if there were, the `|| {}` at the end will never be used, `{...props}` will always result in an object, and objects are not falsy values.

Comment: I agree on the poor practice part. It's development code and for now I was just focussing on getting the update through. Once that works, I will clean it up and work with actual state information that gets updated.

Comment: Tried the first suggestion, it did not fix the issue. Even though it is of course correct (a console.log showed that the state was set to "n" indeed). Thanks for thinking about it, appreciate the effort and tips. Can't figure out why it still won't re-render though.